# How to mark message as read, properly get from address and delete message

Tags: c#, winforms, email, exchangewebservices

It seems as though I can finally access the service and get all unread mails from the inbox by using the EWS API but it seems as though the message doesn't send

```
EmailMessage message = new EmailMessage(emailService);
message.Subject = string.Format("Electricity token for: {0}", house.Number);
message.Body = html.HTMLCode;
message.ToRecipients.Add(email.From);
message.SendAndSaveCopy();
```

"email" refers to the list of unread emails I get back

what must I do to correctly get the senders email address and how do I mark it as read and then delete it?

Comment: Are you trying to reply to an email, mark it as read, and then delete the original email from the sender? If so, you want to bind to the original mail as shown here: [How to: Respond to email messages by using EWS in Exchange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn617213(v=exchg.150).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24427044/error-trying-to-send-mail-not-sending-using-ews), it appears that the problem was indeed that you hadn't bound to the original mail.