# Error trying to send mail. Not sending using EWS

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I'm connecting fine to the Exchange Server and I'm getting all the unread mails but a new message doesn't want to send

Message Code

```
var newHTML = html.HTMLCode.Replace("{House}", house.Number)
                           .Replace("{Token}", token.Number)
                           .Replace("{contactPerson}", 
                                    string.Format("<a href=mailto:{0}>{1}</a>", 
                                    contactPerson, contactPerson));
LogError.WriteToFile("Has House and token");
//Send mail with token to user 
EmailMessage message = new EmailMessage(emailService);
message.ToRecipients.Add(email.From.Address);
message.Subject = string.Format("Electricity token for: {0}", house.Number);
message.Body = new MessageBody(html.HTMLCode);
LogError.WriteToFile("Trying to send");
message.Send();
```

I have a try catch around this so in the log file I get "Trying to send" but then a error occurs that reads as
"EmailAddress or ItemId must be included in the request."

From examples seen, the way I construct my message seems sufficient but clearly isn't

Comment: @JcMey3r Can you extract the solution from your question text and make that an actual answer? You can even mark it as the correct answer after 2 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I got all my unread emails

```
 SearchFilter sf = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, false));
            ItemView view = new ItemView(int.MaxValue);
            FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = emailService.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, sf, view);
            foreach (EmailMessage email in findResults)
            {}
```

Note that I got them as a "EmailMessage"

But were never able to get the senders email address so that's why it didn't want to send.
and then I found this article: [FindItem returns only the first 512 bytes of any streamable property](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brijs/archive/2010/02/12/how-to-retrieve-email-address-from-the-from-and-to-field-of-mail-item-using-ews-managed-api.aspx)

So then I went to go get that specific email like this. Note that I now get the "Item" from the findResults and with that "Item" I do the following.

```
SearchFilter sf = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, false));
            ItemView view = new ItemView(int.MaxValue);
            FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = emailService.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, sf, view);
            foreach (Item item in findResults)
            {
//Get the email message
                    EmailMessage email = EmailMessage.Bind(emailService, item.Id,
                    new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, ItemSchema.Attachments));

                    if (email != null)
                    {}
}
```

Now I could finally send emails